# How to make this code more efficient in Python?

Tags: python, performance, loops, for-loop

I'm having trouble running this nested for loop efficiently. I need to run this loops on a string s whose length is about 90,000. Can anyone provide any tips?

This code is supposed to take a string, and chop it up into pieces n sizes long such that the pieces are a continuous part of the original string. The program then returns the size of each set for n up to the length of the string.

For example: GATTACAT for n = 2 would produce {'GA', 'AT', 'TT', 'TA', 'AC', 'CA', 'AT' }. It would take the set of this so {'GA', 'AT', 'TT', 'TA', 'AC', 'CA'} and return its length.

The program is to do this from n = 0 to n = len('GATTACAT'), and sum all set lengths.

```
for m in range(1, len(s)+1):
    sublist = list()
    for n in range(0, len(s)-m+1):
        sublist.append(''.join(ind[n:n+m]))
    sumS += len(set(sublist))
```

thanks!

Comment: What should this code do?

Comment: Downvotes for letting us guess the purpose of some code fragment. SO is not the guess-my-code game.

Comment: Please use http://codereview.stackexchange.com for reviews of essentially working code.

Comment: What's `ind`?  Note that no matter what it is you're really trying to do, if you want all contiguous slices of lengths 1, 2, 3, ..., and 90000 from a string of length 90000, `sum(xrange(90001)` is 4,050,045,000.  That is, the innermost statement in your loop nest will execute over 4 billion times.  This is going to take a bit of time no matter what you do ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Some quick ideas come to mind:

```
slen = 1 + len(s) # do this once, not a bunch of times in the loop
for m in range(1, slen):
    sublist = [''.join(ind[n:n+m]) for n in range(slen-m))] # list comps are usually faster than loops
    sumS += len(set(sublist))
```

Actually you can probably do it as a larger comprehension:

```
slen = 1 + len(s)
sumS += sum(len(set(''.join(ind[n:n+m]) for n in range(slen-m))) for m in range(1,slen))
```

If you have Python 3 use a set comprehension instead of the list comprehension above.

Comment: Your `slen` optimization doesn't actually do anything, because the `range` object is created and reused -- the expression `1 + len(s)` is only evaluated once.

Comment: @pandubear but there was a second `range` on `len+1` inside the loop. It's a nested loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> s = 'GATTACAT'

>>> [s[i:i+2] for i in range(len(s)-1)]
['GA', 'AT', 'TT', 'TA', 'AC', 'CA', 'AT']

>>> [s[i:i+3] for i in range(len(s)-2)]
['GAT', 'ATT', 'TTA', 'TAC', 'ACA', 'CAT']
```

Comment: The question was about eliminating duplicates too. Put a generator inside `set()` and I think you have it.

Comment: Good enough for a poorly asked question

Comment: And the question is not about eleminating dupes, see given example for n=2

Comment: You should probably use `lamda` for this.

Comment: why would I need a lambda here?

Comment: Oh, *everything* on StackOverflow has to be solved with a lambda. That's the game! No, wait, sorry, that's http://codegolf.stackexchange.com

Comment: @user2799617 funny, I say that about anonymous downvoters. :)